# Use antlr parse sentence

Tags: prolog, antlr3

How to use ANTLR parse the natural sentence?
Exp: John likes mary. In prolog, every thing is simple:

```
s-->np, vp.
np-->[john].
np-->[mary]
vp-->v, np.
v-->[likes].
```

I want to use ANTLR to build the program(in Java) that parse some sentence. I just finished add ANTLR into eclipse,  but the guide in http://www.antlr.org/wiki is very difficult for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANTLR is not well-suited to [natural language processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) because it only allows a sentence to be interpreted one way.

Comment: Yes, i know. But it is my homework in school: "Use ANTLR build parser for each sentence: .....". It's my problem!